# How to ensure the ipython and python3 versions match when installing them through homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

Currently, the default version of python3 installed through homebrew is 3.10.9. However, the default version of ipython depends on python 3.11.1, which is automatically installed with homebrew.

The problem is that if I install a package via pip, it will not be recognized in ipython because of [how homebrew manages different python versions](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python).

Is it possible to ensure ipython uses the same version of python as homebrew's default version?

I understand there are other solutions like using pyenv to manage different versions of python, but I am looking for a solution that only requires homebrew.

I have tried the command `brew unlink python@3.10`, but it removes the `python3` symbolic link, which means I have to update the symbolic link manually to point to the desired version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After updating macos to Python 3.11

```
brew install python@3.11
```

and removing the 3.10 link like above

```
brew unlink python3.10
```

I simply updated ipython from 3.8 to 3.12

```
python3 -m pip install ipython
```

Now ipython is using Python 3.11

```
❯ ipython
Python 3.11.2 (main, Mar 24 2023, 00:28:48) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)]
```